# Pandas HDFStore: Saving and Retrieving a Series with Hierarchical Period Index

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, indexing, hdfstore

I first create a series with a two dimensional hierarchical index. They index type is (pandas.period, numpy.int32)

```
In [265]: import pandas as pd

In [266]: import numpy as np

In [267]: hdf_file = r'F:\test.h5'

In [268]: data = np.random.randint(10, size=(7, 3))

In [269]: dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2015', '1/7/2015').to_period('D')

In [270]: ts1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index = dates, columns = [1, 2, 3]).stack()
```

Then, I save the series (ts1) using HDFStore and retrieve it (as ts2):

```
In [271]: with pd.HDFStore(hdf_file, 'w') as store:
     ...:     store['ts'] = ts1
     ...:     

In [272]: with pd.HDFStore(hdf_file, 'r') as store:
     ...:     ts2 = store['ts']
     ...:
```

Now, the dtype of the index of the retrieved series (ts2) has been changed to integer:

```
In [273]: print(ts1)
2015-01-01  1    3
            2    8
            3    0
2015-01-02  1    2
            2    3
            3    9
2015-01-03  1    9
            2    2
            3    2
2015-01-04  1    4
            2    5
            3    1
2015-01-05  1    2
            2    1
            3    6
2015-01-06  1    1
            2    0
            3    8
2015-01-07  1    0
            2    6
            3    8
dtype: int32

In [274]: print(ts2)
16436  1    3
       2    8
       3    0
16437  1    2
       2    3
       3    9
16438  1    9
       2    2
       3    2
16439  1    4
       2    5
       3    1
16440  1    2
       2    1
       3    6
16441  1    1
       2    0
       3    8
16442  1    0
       2    6
       3    8
dtype: int32
```

Is there a way to save the series properly? I know I can change the type after I retrieve the data, but I prefer to do the job cleanly.

I am using pandas 0.16.1 and pyhon 2.7.7 (Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not implemented see the issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7796)

save as timestamps and convert to Periods after read back